# jquery hover alternate not working in IE10

Tags: jquery, css, hover, internet-explorer-10

I have an navigation with two levels.

```
<ul id="level1">
  <li id="Level1ListItemOne">
      <ul id="Level2">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        ...
     </ul>  
 </li>
  <li id="Level1ListItemTwo">
      <ul id="Level2">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        ...
     </ul> 
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

When the page opens Level1ListItemOne Level2 is visible. 
When the user hovers over Level1ListItemTwo then Level2 of Level1ListItemOne disappears and Level2 of Level1ListItemTwo appears.
When the user hovers away from Level1ListItemTwo then Level2 of Level1ListItemOne reappears.

I am doing this with JQuery

```
jQuery("#Level1ListItemTwo").hover(
    function(){ 
        jQuery("#Level1ListItemOne> #level2").hide(); //hide level2 when hover over
        jQuery("#Level1ListItemOne").css("background-color","#003366");
    },
    function(){
        jQuery("#Level1ListItemOne> #level2").show(); //show level2 when hover out
        jQuery("#Level1ListItemOne").css("background-color","#0072c6");
    }
);
```

This works perfectly in FireFox, Chrome, IE9 but **not** IE10

In IE10 it works the first time but not after that. So Level2 of Level1ListItemTwo never reappears.
What is IE10 doing differently - I can't see anything in developer tools!

Comment: try jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: the jquery above is inside jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {});

Comment: You are using same id `Level2` for the `ul` lists. If you want both the items to have same `id` name, better use `class`, because element ids should be unique within the entire document.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because your `id` in not correct because of case sensitivity.

jQuery's class selector uses the javascript method `getElementsByClassName` if the browser supports it. This method is case-insensitive on quirks-mode pages, and case-sensitive on non-quirksmode (standards-compliant) pages.

Another tip, id must be unique inside your page, so switch to class instead of id.

Code:

```
jQuery("#Level1ListItemTwo").hover(
    function(){ 
        jQuery("#Level1ListItemOne>.Level2").hide(); //hide level2 when hover over
        jQuery("#Level1ListItemOne").css("background-color","#003366");
    },
    function(){
        jQuery("#Level1ListItemOne>.Level2").show(); //show level2 when hover out
        jQuery("#Level1ListItemOne").css("background-color","#0072c6");
    }
);
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Case_Sensitivity_in_class_and_id_Names

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W9GL4/

Comment: thanks for this, but I think I'll have to stick with id's as the HTML that is being rendered out already has many classes applied. I am trying to customise a SharePoint navigation control, so it's not that straight forward

Comment: @user3441600 I think you can't id must be unique as per definition